# Excel: Indefinite number of rows in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Google Sheets you can reference all rows (no matter how many there are) by simply leaving out the number of the last row: `=XLOOKUP("Orange";B2:B;A2:A)` By this notation XLOOKUP runs through all rows from 2 until the very last one; you don't have to know and specify the last row.

What is the best or most efficient way in Excel to do so?

Comment: You could convert your data to table

Comment: If it's not a too big of a table, you can also just search the entire column, i.e. `=XLOOKUP("Orange";B:B;A:A)`

Comment: @user11222393 A table could be a good workaround but is not flexible to use.

Comment: @Notus_panda That won't work with us because the headline sometimes contains same values.

Comment: The old-fashioned way _is_ to create a [dynamic-named range](https://exceljet.net/formulas/dynamic-named-range-with-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, but not the best way is to take the maximum number of rows that you expect to have and write it in the formula. For instance, if you are certain that you will never have more than 2000 rows, just write `B2:B2000`.

The disadvantage is that you now possibly have many empty rows in your range.

The best, but not the simplest way, is to put the data through a limiter formula. I created one such function called TrimToData here:
https://gist.github.com/ttarchala/1cbdfab59b4c6d97cf77fec651f5475c

If you import the gist using Excel Labs, you can then use

```
=XLOOKUP("Orange";TrimToData(B2:B2000);TrimToData(A2:A2000))
```

Which has the added benefit of detecting if your A and B columns don't have the same number of values in them.

Comment: Thank You very much. Okay, so then this known method of the old days is still the way to go with Excel. Good to know that we don't miss a better way, sad to know, that Microsoft hasn't implemented the other way.